# Creating Gosper Curve by geometry

Tags: geometry

I am reading a book by "Fractals, Chaos and Power Laws" by Manfred Schroeder.On page 13, it produces seven fractal tiles from seven hexagons by breaking up each side into a three-piece zigzag as shown one of the sides.

Here is [the picture](http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/panorama/ManuFractals/FractalFiberoptics/Gosper/GosperCurve.html)

and it further claims that if the angles of the three pieces are $120^{\circ}$, then the lengths of the three segments will be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}$ times the length of the unbroken side.

I can not figure out how he got $\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}$ from the figure above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way. Note that for each side $s$, the three new sides and $s$ form two triangles like this

$\hspace{8em}$[image: triangle with labelled sides and angles]

where $c = s/2$, $a = b/2$, and $\gamma = 120^{\circ}$. Now, [we know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent_rules) that
$$
c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos(\gamma)
$$
Recalling that $\cos(120^{\circ}) = -1/2$ and making the appropriate substitutions we have
$$
\frac{s^2}{4} = \frac{b^2}{4} + b^2 + \frac{b^2}{2} = \frac{7}{4} b^2
$$
Finally, multiplying by $4$ and taking square roots this gives
$$
s = \sqrt{7} \, b
$$